# Make macOS look like a Linux desktop

Tags: macos, unix, desktop

I have been developing under GNU/Linux systems for the last 10 years. Unfortunately my company is going to move developers to macOS systems soon.

Although for most of the part I should be ok (after all, people use programs, not Operative Systems), there are a couple of problems that I need to solve, most of them around having a desktop similar to the one in Linux Mint (Cinnamom), but actually anything looking like gnome2 would do.

Is it possible to install a Linux-like desktop in macOS (or maybe configure macOS to look like a Linux desktop). Essentially I am looking for a simple bottom bar with a couple of links to main applications and a list of opened windows (see image).

[image]

Is this possible?

I have searched for this, and what I tend to find is the opposite process, how to make Linux desktops look like macOS desktops...

Comment: It does not have to look exactly like linux mint, but is it a least possible to have a theme with a normal app bar instead of the osx one?

Answer (score 3):

Just an alternative viewpoint to consider:

Trying to make MacOS appear and behave like Linux (or like Windows, or vice versa) is doomed to failure, because at some point the illusion will break down. There are things that are completely, inherently, and essentially different, which cannot be changed.

The more you pretend that they are the same, the bigger the shock or obstacle when those differences emerge.

I know we all have muscle memory for shortcuts and positions of things, but it doesn't take long to train yourself. The human brain is more programmable than any computer, after all.

Comment: Also well written apps use Operating Systems APIs to integrate, this keeps all good apps behaving similar to each other eg Xcode, Visual Stuio Code, Pages, Numbers all have a similar menu and keyboard structure. Linux and other Unixes are the odd ones out as they usually don't provide guidelines for writing apps and so they all behave differently.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [ubar](https://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar). It gives you similar style task-bar.

But if you really want to get benefit from macOS, check out these great tools: [Launchbar](https://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html), [iStatmenus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/)

For discovering other useful utilities, checkout [Macupdate](https://www.macupdate.com/apps/14/maximizing-your-menu-bar)

Comment: Alfred 3 is a nice Launchbar alternative and, in my view, easier to use and more comprehensive. That said, Launchbar remains free and Alfred, while free for basic functions, requires a purchase for the "good" stuff!

Comment: What are main differences in LaunchBar and Dropzone?

Comment: What productivity benefits does iStatMenus provide?

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is from 2+ years ago, but some things never change.  The desire to customize MacOS, as well as the incessant drum beat of "nope you can't do it."  Other wrong answers include:

- Embrace change
- it's better this way
- Once you get used to it, you'll like it

I happen to believe that the UI of an operating system should be customizable.  I want it to work MY way.  If that means mapping the caps-lock key to cycle between workspaces, that's my prerogative.  If I want to change window toggling so it works like KDE/Gnome/Windows, that is my choice.

And I want a 'start' menu on MacOS, that is between me and the universe.

Another fundamental that never changes:  Where there's a will, there's a way.  I'm pretty sure I'm not alone in wanting to customize the heck out of OSX considering how many tools out there are designed for exactly this purpose. Check out the tools written by manytricks.com (No affiliation).  Their apps are not free but look promising.

Rather than trying to make it look completely like Gnome, focus on specific annoyances or things that slow you down.  Whether it's alt-tab or other behaviors you want.  Focus on the behaviors you want changed and you'll probably find tools that will do what you want.

One word of caution:  Many of these tools require the "accessibility" feature of the OS.  If your employer has turned that off in the name of security, you might be out of luck.

I'm sorry to say, the best I've found is articles on how to make MacOS look/feel like Windows, not X/Gnome/KDE.  You may have some luck reading through those articles and picking specific UI behaviors you want.
[https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-make-mac-look-like-windows-10/#:~:text=How%20to%20make%20your%20Mac%20look%20like%20Windows,switching.%20On%20Windows%2C%20Alt%2BTab%20cycles%20...%20More%20items](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-make-mac-look-like-windows-10/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20make%20your%20Mac%20look%20like%20Windows,switching.%20On%20Windows%2C%20Alt%2BTab%20cycles%20...%20More%20items)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).